# How to call other function with same name while still allowing ADL etc

Tags: c++

How do I make the call in the second `f()` find the first `f()` with an unqualified lookup so ADL and normal name lookup rules would still work?

Note: I don't want to change the name of any of the functions.

```
namespace x 
{
    void f()
    {
    }

    class C 
    {
        void f() 
        {
            x::f();
        }
    };
}
```

Comment: `::f()` doesn't work?

Comment: @barakmanos "with an unqualified lookup so ADL and normal name lookup rules would still work"

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Just bring in the function:

```
void f()
{
    using x::f;
    f(); // calls x::f()
}
```

The reason this works is, to copy [Mike Seymour's answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/27316662/2069064):

> Because the using declaration brings x::f into the scope of f, which is narrower than that of C. Unqualified lookup considers the local block scope, finds a match, and stops before considering the wider class scope. There is no argument-dependent lookup since there are no function arguments, so no further scopes are considered.

Comment: Much to my surprise, this works. I would have expected it to result in an ambiguous call. Can you explain why this doesn't happen?

Comment: @Angew To be honest I'm surprised too. I'm trying to find something in the standard that would somehow distinguish between the two calls but I can't.

Comment: Looks like a budding [tag:language-lawyer] question to me. I'll ask it, unless you want to.

Comment: @Angew I'll ask it. At this point I'm like 30 minutes into the Overload Resolution secution and still got nothing so now I *really* want to know.

Answer (score 0):

You could create a wrapper:

```
namespace x
{
  void f()
  {
  }

  void call_f()
  {
    f();
  }

  class C
  {
    void f()
    {
      call_f();
    }
  };
}
```