# Overload Resolution: How is this not ambiguous?

Tags: c++, language-lawyer, overload-resolution

Suppose we have this code, copied from a separate question:

```
namespace x 
{
    void f()
    {
    }

    class C 
    {
        void f() 
        {
            using x::f;
            f();         // <==
        }
    };
}
```

The name `f` on the indicated line unambiguously refers to `x::f` (at least according to both gcc and clang). Why is `x::f` preferred over `x::C::f` in this case? Shouldn't it be ambiguous as both names are visible?

Answer (score 10, accepted):

Because the `using` declaration brings `x::f` into the scope of `f`, which is narrower than that of `C`. Unqualified lookup considers the local block scope, finds a match, and stops before considering the wider class scope. There is no argument-dependent lookup since there are no function arguments, so no further scopes are considered.

Answer (score 7):

@MikeSeymour's answer is spot on; here are the relevant standard quotes (C++11, emphasis mine):

13.3.1.1.1/3:

> In unqualified function calls, the name is not qualified by an `->` or `.` operator and has the more general form
>   of a *primary-expression.* The name is looked up in the context of the function call following the normal rules
>   for name lookup in function calls (3.4). The function declarations found by that lookup constitute the set of
>   candidate functions. **Because of the rules for name lookup, the set of candidate functions consists (1) entirely
>   of non-member functions or (2) entirely of member functions of some class `T`.** ...

3.4.1/1:

> In all the cases listed in 3.4.1, the scopes are searched for a declaration in the order listed in each of the
>   respective categories; name lookup ends as soon as a declaration is found for the name. If no declaration is
>   found, the program is ill-formed.

3.4.1/8

> A name used in the definition of a member function (9.3) of class `X` following the function's *declarator-id*
>   ... shall be declared in one of
>   the following ways:
>
> - before its use in the block in which it is used or in an enclosing block (6.3), or
> - shall be a member of class `X` or be a member of a base class of `X` (10.2), or
> - ...

From 3.4.1/8, we see that a declaration for the name `f` (such as the declaration `using x::f;`) in the block in which it's used is listed earlier than `f` as the member of class `C`. As per 3.4.1/1, the earlier one is chosen, so the entire lookup resolves to `x::f` introduced by the `using` declaration.

Answer (score 1):

I think that these quotes from the C++ Standard will be relevant:

From the C++ Standard (7.3.3 The using declaration)

> 13 Since a using-declaration is a declaration, the restrictions on
>   declarations of the same name in the same declarative region (3.3)
>   also apply to using-declarations.

And (3.3.7 Class scope)

> 4) A name declared within a member function hides a declaration of the
>   same name whose scope extends to or past the end of the member
>   function’s class.